# Excel find keywords in text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an export of various OUs in active directory and import it into Excel, but I need to label each row by category or keyword. So I have a sheet of categories and I want to loop through the categories per cell (or AD OU).

This is what I have so far, but it is only singular and doesn't allow for multiple search/category/keyword terms.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Keywords'!A1,B1)),'Keywords'!B1)
```

Comment: Using wild card `*` in `INDEX/MATCH` may work for you.  But without seeing real data structure, it is hard to help.  Maybe post a screenshot or markup data so we can further assist you.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, I'm assuming you have 2 columns on your Keywords sheet. Column A has your keywords and Column B has the Category you want returned.

If you have 10 rows of keywords and categories, this formula will find the category for the first matching keyword found in cell B1 in the current sheet:

```
=INDEX(Keywords!$B$1:$B$10,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Keywords!$A$1:$A$10,B1)),0))
```

Note that this is an array formula. To enter it correctly, you need to copy this formula, double click into the cell where you want the formula, paste the formula, then press `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` to save the formula.

You'll need to update the ranges on your Keywords spreadsheet to include all rows of keywords and categories. You need to re-save the formula using `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` every time you edit it.

Comment: I tried and I am not sure if I explained it wrong, of if it is not working.
I have one work book that has AD OUs (quite a bit to do this by hand), for example

`OU=IT department,OU=HQ,DC=Company,DC=com`
and
`OU=HR department,OU=HQ,DC=Company,DC=com`
On a second sheet I have a cell for each of the departments, IT, HR, etc

I would to look for the departments inside of each OU and label them with that departments name.

Comment: That still doesn't explain enough I'm afraid. Please take a screenshot of each worksheet (including an example of your desired result) and save both screenshots as pictures. Edit your question and click the picture icon to upload both pictures.